# CSV data comparison in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have 2 MySQL tables and want to compare the value of a column in one table with the value of a column in the other table; the data is stored in CSV format. I want to know how to compare the two values?

Example:

> Candidate skills in candidate table are like java,html,sql
>
> Job skills in job table are like jquery,html,css

Now I have a job requirement of `jquery,html,css`, so to get the list of candidates that are at least one tech requirement match to the candidate:

> $sql = 'select co.corp_contact_num, co.corp_name,
>   co.corp_contact_person, co.corp_email_id, co.corp_address,
>   co.corp_email_id, co.corp_url, c.corp_id, c.cand_id, c.cand_name,
>   c.cand_email_id, c.cand_current_location, c.cand_preferred_location,
>   c.cand_rate_per_hour, c.cand_position_title,
>                                c.cand_experience, c.cand_technical_skills, c.cand_Domain_skills, c.cand_leadership_skills, c.cand_certifications,
>   c.cand_clients from candidates c join corporations co where c.corp_id
>   = co.corp_id and c.is_available = "1" and co.corp_id != "'.$_SESSION['sess_corp_id'].'" and c.cand_technical_skills
>   LIKE"%'.$check. '%"';

Comment: i have 2 table candidate and job and having columns candidate skill job skills. now i want to matched candidates for my job requirements? for that mysql query

Comment: You can repeate more and more times but the code is better.....

Comment: With respect, using SQL to search this kind of denormalized data set is like trying to drive screws with a hammer. You can do it, but it will make a big mess and work poorly. Can you consider normalizing your data, so each item (like "jquery" or "nodejs") appears in its own row?